# How to increment json object properties values to dynamically populate the json body of a jmeter request

Tags: json, jmeter

Using JMeter I need to send a request which contains a body in such a format:

```
  {
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":{
          "key21":[
             {
                "key211_1":"valueA",
                "key212_1":"valueToIncrement",
                "key213_1":{
                   "key2131_1":"valueB",
                   "key2132_1":"valueC",
                },
                "key214_1":{
                   "key2141_1":"valueD",
                   "key2142_1":"valueE"
                }
             },
             {
                "key211_2":"valueA",
                "key212_2":"valueToIncrement+1",
                "key213_2":{
                   "key2131_2":"valueB",
                   "key2132_2":"valueC",
                },
                "key214_2":{
                   "key2141_2":"valueD",
                   "key2142_2":"valueE"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Inside the body I can have a list of many json objects and each object will have some property with an unique id inside the request.

Something like:

```
{
"key212_1":"1"
},
{
"key212_2":"2"
}
...
{
"key212_2":"n"
}
```

Because I can have hundreds of objects inside a request body, can I create a logic in Jmeter, so that each time a request is sent, each value from the target property would have a value incremented by 1 in each of these properties without having to manually hardcode values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to maintain `Counter`. At the request where you want to increment the value, add a `JSR223 Pre Processor`. In that you will have to code to increment the value and save it back to the variable and also assign it your Json object.

**EDIT** :- I tried to simulate your setup as below.

**Setup**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**RESULT**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried your setup and I noticed that it only increases the finalJsonObj values when the iteration increases. In the Thread Group, if I set up 4 interations, the outcome will be as in your screenshot, but if I select 1 iteration and 4 threads, each sampler will get one json object which is not composed like this:
finalJsonObj=[{"incrValue":"1"}]
finalJsonObj=[{"incrValue":"2"}]
finalJsonObj=[{"incrValue":"3"}]
finalJsonObj=[{"incrValue":"4"}]
I was expecting
finalJsonObj=[{"incrValue":"1"},"incrValue":"2"},"incrValue":"3"}."incrValue":"4"}]
four times.

Comment: Got it. Just one change in your `JSR223 Preprocessor`. Update line #10 as below `finalJsonObj = myObj`

Comment: I did the change, saved and reran but there is no update in behavior.

Comment: UPDATE: Ah wait, I see the change now: if I put 4 threads and 2 iterations, each request has one json object with an incremented value, which is good, that's what I wanted. Thx.

Comment: I needed to use a for loop in the PreProc to create one dynamically-changing "big" Json object from 3 smaller json Objects (myObj1,myObj2,myObj3) used for the deeper-level branches and on each loop I just increase a counter variable declared directly in the JSR223 PreProcessor script up to the number of "big" objects I need. At the end of each loop I add the "big" Json to one masterJsonObject and once all the iterations finish, I put the dynamically-composed master object into a variable.
Then this variable is available to use in the HTTP Request body in the middle of some static json body.

Comment: Although your solution was not exactly what I needed, you gave me the building blocks I needed so I just want you to know that I am very grateful! Thanks!
Do you by any chance know how I can do the same for an XML request? I guess I would need an to use an equivalent library to this JsonSlurper that works for XML object compositions.